# Cómo detectar que un punto está dentro de un polígono usando Google Maps SDK para iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift4

Con el SDK de Google Maps para iOS, es posible detectar que un punto está dentro de un polígono?

He encontrado la función containsLocation() de JavaScript de Google Maps API, sin embargo, no pude encontrar el mismo en el SDK de iOS.

¿Conoce alguna otra manera?

Encontre esto:

```
if GMSGeometryContainsLocation(yourPoint, pathOfPolygon, true) {
    print("YES: you are in this polygon.")
} else {
    print("You do not appear to be in this polygon.")
}
```

pero la verdad no se como usar

```
GMSGeometryContainsLocation (CLLocationCoordinate2D point, GMSPath *path, BOOL geodesic)
```

con el `GMSPath *path`

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Nunca he utilizado ese método pero si tu problema es el llamado de parámetros podría ser algo a si.

```
        let pointTmp = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.35, longitude: -122.0)
```

para el otro podría ser algo a si:

```
// Create a rectangular path
let rect = GMSMutablePath()
rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.0))
rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.45, longitude: -122.0))
rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.45, longitude: -122.2))
rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.2))

// Crea el polígono y asígnalo al mapa.
let polygon = GMSPolygon(path: rect)
 polygon.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.25, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.05);
 //polygon.strokeColor = .black
 //polygon.strokeWidth = 2
 //polygon.map = mapView

 // el path de llama a si:
 polyLine.path
```

Eso crea dos valores posibles para el método al que quieres llamar.
Eso son ejemplos nadamas.

Te anexo el link de donde los obtuve.

[Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes?hl=es-419)